# Trying to convert jQuery to Google app scripts to display information in sheets

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is the jQuery code:

```
var settings = {
  "url": "https://services.sia.homeoffice.gov.uk/PublicRegister/SearchPublicRegisterByLicence?LicenseNo=1012894854698842",
  "method": "POST",
  "timeout": 0,
  "headers": {
    "Cookie": "cookiesession1=346BFCF7VNLBSDHWI3GLRB0XOBNO1458"
  },
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

This is my Appscript Code

```
function myFunction() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://services.sia.homeoffice.gov.uk/PublicRegister/Sea rchPublicRegisterByLicence?LicenseNo=1012894854698842");
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

This is the information I want laid out into sheets

- First name
- Surname
- Licence number
- Role
- Licence sector
- Door Supervision
- Expiry date
- Status
- Active (as on 31 August 2018)
- Status explanation
- Active
- Additional licence conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You should add options to your request in Apps Script

Here's my approach:

```
// Just in case your payload needs body
var data = {
  'example': 'example',
  'test': ['test', 'test']
};
var options = {
  'method' : 'post',
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'headers': {
    'Cookie': 'cookiesession1=346BFCF7VNLBSDHWI3GLRB0XOBNO1458'
  },
  'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
};

UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://services.sia.homeoffice.gov.uk/PublicRegister/SearchPublicRegisterByLicence?LicenseNo=1012894854698842', options);

Logger.log(response.getContentText());
```

Where options has the entire payload and not the default GET that UrlFetchApp provides when using the [fetch(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl) method

### References

- [UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl)
- [UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: Thank You for your response, I am getting an error on appscript telling me it cant save

Comment: Can you please share that error like an image or text?

Comment: Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected string line: 14 file: Code.gs

Comment: function myFunction() {

// Just in case your payload needs body
var data = {
  'example': 'example',
  'test': ['test', 'test']
};
var options = {
  'method' : 'post',
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'headers': {
    'Cookie': 'cookiesession1=346BFCF7VNLBSDHWI3GLRB0XOBNO1458'
  }
  'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
};

UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://services.sia.homeoffice.gov.uk/PublicRegister/SearchPublicRegisterByLicence?LicenseNo=1012894854698842', options);

Logger.log(response.getContentText());

Comment: I updated my answer, a comma was missing.

Comment: Thanks, 
any idea what this means? and how I can extract the results into sheets
The website gives me information from the licence number search and I just want that data in a sheet
Logging output too large. Truncating output.

Comment: Yes you can integrate the results into sheets by using [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) in Apps Script.

Comment: Sorry I am stuck on how to do this,